# Pseudo determinant of a block matrix with invertible subblock

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Consider the following formula for the determinant when $A$ is nonsingular,
$$
\det \begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix} = \det (A) \det (D - C A^{-1}B).
$$

I am thinking if $A$ is non-singular, however, the full matrix is singular, then does the following equation hold?
$$
Det \begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix} = Det (A) Det (D - C A^{-1}B),
$$
where $Det$ denotes the [pseudo determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant).

Comment: No. When $A=B=C=D=1$, the LHS is $2$ but the RHS is $1$ (because $\operatorname{Det}(D-CA^{-1}B)=\operatorname{Det}(0)$ is an empty product).